# Call parameterized javascript function from servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

The button "Refresh for New Query"    is for lazy users who doesn't wish to type their query and instead read it from file and store in String variable h. If user clicks on that "Refresh for new Query!" button, i wish to place the text read from the file in the textfield and automatically call the Search submit button.

But I'm not able to pass the parameter string value from Servlet into the javascript function. Also I know nothing about AJAX or JQuery, so answers in javascript would be appreciated. Also I may be wrong in the form design itself as I am a naive user.

```
String h="test";
writer.append("<html>\n");
writer.append("<head>\n");
writer.append(String.format("<title>%s - My Search</title>\n", displayQuery));
writer.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
writer.append("function display(k) {\n");
writer.append("   var object =k ;\n");
writer.append("document.getElementById('textfield1').value=object;\n")
writer.append("document.form.submit \n")
writer.append("  }\n");
writer.append("</script>\n");
writer.append("</head>\n<body>\n");
writer.append("</head>");
writer.append("<body>");
writer.append("<div id=\"Layer1\">");
writer.append("<form action=\"search\">");
writer.append("<input type=\"text\" id=\"textfield1\" name=\"q\" placeholder=\"Search here...\">");
writer.append("<input id=\"gobutton1\"type=\"submit\" value=\"Search\"/>");
writer.append("</form>");
writer.append(String.format("<a href=\"search?q=%s&start=%d&n=%d\"><input id=\"gobutton\"  type=\"button\" value=\"Refresh for New Query!\" onClick=\"display('"+h+"')\"/></a>",h,0,10));
writer.append("</div>");
```

.......

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the info page on servlets: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info  You should use JSP to display HTML, and the servlet to feed values to it, not print out HTML like this in a servlet.  Its not readable; its a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters from Servlet to JavaScript, it's make easy. 
But you should know that JavaScript is not processed on the server- side, it will be executed in the browser.

Simple example:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/myservlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("<html><head>"+
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
        "function cc()"+
        "{alert("+new Date()+")}"+
        "</script>"+
        "</head>"+
        "<body>"+
        "<input type='button' value='click me money' onclick='cc()'>"+
        "</body>"+
        "</html>");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Definitely worth a try. But I have another question, If i have a variable say x of type string, then will the line {alert("+ x +")} work?